# C# Blink Label Class

Tags: c#, label, blink

I am trying to create a class that makes a particular textbox blink. My code is below:

```
class Blink
{
    int BlinkCount = 0;

    public void Text(Label Info, string Message)
    {
        Timer tmrBlink = new Timer();
        tmrBlink.Interval = 250;
        tmrBlink.Tick += new System.EventHandler(tmrBlink_Tick);
        tmrBlink.Start();
        Info.Text = Message;
    }

    private void tmrBlink_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BlinkCount++;

        if (Info.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Khaki)
        {
            Info.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
        else
        {
            Info.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Khaki;
        }

        if (BlinkCount == 4)
        {
            tmrBlink.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is, if I type the following code, the selected label would blink to draw user's attention:

```
Blink.Text(lblControl, "Hello World!");
```

Comment: are you using winforms or WPF ?

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: I don't see a question either.  There's a bunch of stuff missing.  You need to subscribe the label's Disposed event.  And when the blink is stopped, either because the label is disposed or the blink is completed, then you need to unsubscribe the event and dispose the timer.

Comment: Sorry, the question is it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me...

```
Blink b = new Blink();
b.Text(label1, "Hello World");


class Blink
{
    int BlinkCount = 0;
    private Label _info;
    private Timer _tmrBlink;

    public void Text(Label info, string message)
    {
        _info = info;
        _info.Text = message;
        _tmrBlink = new Timer();
        _tmrBlink.Interval = 250;
        _tmrBlink.Tick += new System.EventHandler(tmrBlink_Tick);
        _tmrBlink.Start();
    }

    private void tmrBlink_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BlinkCount++;

        if (_info.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Khaki)
        {
            _info.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
        else
        {
            _info.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Khaki;
        }

        if (BlinkCount == 4)
        {
            _tmrBlink.Stop();
            BlinkCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what changes you have made that fixed the issue. If this is just a comment explaining that it works as written to you then that should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: Oh, I didnt declare the controls at the top. Thanks, you guys are fast!